# Should I flag questions that were closed for the wrong reason?

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336511/why-doesnt-this-code-work-on-the-a-live-server), for example, I voted to close as "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error." The majority (3 users) voted that "it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem." Should I flag this, or should I let it go since it was closed anyway?

Comment: What would be the purpose of the flag to have moderators reopen it and then close it again with the correct close reason?

Comment: I say leave it and if you see the same users are closing again and again with invalid closing reason, you might flag to get the moderators attention.

Comment: If they are closed already and you think it is correct they are closed, then I would not flag them again.

Comment: I looked at the question and find that "lacks sufficient information" is right on the money. The problem has *not* been resolved but *could* be resolved if more information was provided.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I would gladly handle such flags myself... once I eventually get to them. But only if the existing close reason truly does not apply (or no longer applies).

Comment: Sounds like a waste of everyone's time.  If you think the OP will be confused, post a comment.